# Keyboard hides UITableView in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am developing an iPhone app. I have a simple `UITableView` on my `ViewController`. In the `UITableView`, I am adding a `UITextField` in a cell. My Problem is when I click on the `UITextField` in a particular cell, the keyboard hides the whole `UITableView`. I have searched about it, but could not successfully find a solution. I am adding `UITextField` like this:

```
UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 15, 60, 30)];
textField.delegate = self;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
textField.tag =TEXT_VIEW_TAG;
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

If anyone knows its solution, then please let me know.

Comment: Kindly provide the code of your table view data source & delegate methods for more insight of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `UITableViewController` can actually handle this by its own. However, if you really do need to use `UITableView` but still want the keyboard not to hide your `UITableView`, then you will need to move your `UITableView` upward when keyboard is on. To do this, you can either change the y position in the `UITextFieldBeginEditing` method or you can use UIKeyboard notifications. You will need to add the below lines of code in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myKeyboardWillHideHandler:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myKeyboardWillShowHandler:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

And then, you can add these methods like:

```
    - (void) myKeyboardWillHideHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame = CGRectMake(YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.origin.x, YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.origin.y + 80, YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.size.width, YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.size.height);
            }];
        }

    - (void) myKeyboardWillShowHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame = CGRectMake(YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.origin.x, YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.origin.y - 80, YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.size.width, YOUR_TBL_VIEW.frame.size.height);
            }];


}
```

Comment: thanks a lot yr... thank u so much. Finally its solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to your code in textFieldDidBeginEditing method

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,textField.center.y-170) animated:YES];
```

Here 170 is the value suitable to me, u can try other.
Hoping it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the `UITableViewController` class instead of `UIViewController` which will solve your problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

one single line of code in your TextBeginEditing

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexpath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

it will make your that row on top there are so many positions are there you can change accordingly.